# How do I plot a probability density graph on MATLAB

Tags: matlab, random, matlab-figure, probability-density

I have a set of randomly generated data that I want to plot on the probability density graph to show that they are 'bad' randomly generated data. I tried using ksdensity but the graph is not what I was looking for.

This is the graph I am looking for
[image]

And here is how I generated my random numbers.

```
x = rand(1);
r = 3.99;
X1 = zeros(5000,1);

for i = 1:5000
for j = 1:1

    X1(i,j) = r*x*(1-x);

    %For next iteration%
    x = X1(i,j); 

end
end

disp(X1);
plot(X1);
title("Generated Data Sequence for 5000 Iterations");
xlabel("Iteration Number n"); ylabel("X_n");
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Not a matlab user, but how about a [histogram](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.histogram.html)?

Answer (score 3):

This should do it. Add at the end:

```
h=linspace(min(X1(:)), max(X1(:)), 200)';
[n,~]=histc(X1(:), h);
pdfX=n/trapz(h,n);

figure
plot(h,pdfX)
```

Comment: Welcome to the site! Note that `histc` is deprecated. You can use `histcounts` instead; or directly `histogram(X1, 201, 'Normalization', 'pdf')`

Comment: Oh yes @LuisMendo 's answer is much more consise and therefore I think better!

Comment: Feel free to incorporate that into your answer (if so let me know and we can delete comments to avoid confusion)

Comment: Thanks to the both of you! I didn't know it was under histogram. I kept searching for pdf but couldn't come out with a graph like that from the picture.